Give an imported image a specific name to avoid repeatedly adding the same images
I import images from a folder onto a PowerPoint slide. I found if I re-run the macro it adds the same picture each time (i.e. if I run the macro four times there will be four of the same picture). I need to run this macro a few times.
I'd like to add a line that deletes the pictures if they're already there before adding again, but .Delete only works if you know the specific image name (i.e. "picture 2"). Every time the images are imported by the macro however they are given some random number.
Is there any way to control the number of the picture when importing it (i.e. assign "picture 1") or to avoid repeatedly adding the same images?
Set plot1 = .Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath & "image.png", LinkToFile = False, SaveWithDocument = True, Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=180, Height:=160)


After inserting each picture for the first time, give it a name based on the full path from which it was inserted - to avoid problems with path length you could hash the path eg using https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1206b3e17c6b01a7838 and use the generated hash for the name.


Iterate through all shapes to validate their names.
Insert a new image if the desired shape does not exist.

Sub Demo()
    Dim plot1 As Shape, imagePath As String, bFound As Boolean
    Const IMG_NAME = "MyPic"
    With ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)
        For Each plot1 In .Shapes
            If plot1.Name = IMG_NAME Then
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not bFound Then
            imagePath = "d:\temp\"
            Set plot1 = .Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath & "image.png", _
                LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
                Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=180, Height:=160)
            plot1.Name = "MyPic"
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Another approach is delete the desired image if found, then insert new image

Sub Demo()
    Dim plot1 As Shape, imagePath As String
    Const IMG_NAME = "MyPic"
    With ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)
        For Each plot1 In .Shapes
            If plot1.Name = IMG_NAME Then
                plot1.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        imagePath = "d:\temp\"
        Set plot1 = .Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath & "image.png", _
            LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
            Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=180, Height:=160)
        plot1.Name = "MyPic"
    End With
End Sub

